# Why am I getting this JsonObjectRequest error? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, json, android-studio, android-volley, jsonobjectrequest

So I am a beginner and I am trying to build a weather app. This is my get weather method

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("Main","in resume");
    getWeather();
}

  public void getWeather(){

    String URL="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=44.3839494&lon=26.0142029&units=metric&appid=05d4d77250a25ed56da43a761a03d7d5";

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("Main",response.toString());
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.d("Main","myerror");
        }
    });

    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);


}
```

My Logcat response is myerror. Why isn't my JSONObject printing?
Stack trace

> D/stacktrace: java.lang.Exception
>           at com.example.weatherflavia.MainActivity.getWeather(MainActivity.java:113)
>           at com.example.weatherflavia.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:93)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1412)
>           at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7292)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3807)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3847)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityItem.java:51)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:145)
>           at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1836)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6702)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:911)

Comment: It helps to also post the specific error you are getting, and maybe a description of what you expect.

Comment: The stack trace would be helpful